# Parcel: unable to marshal value android.graphics.Path

Tags: java, android

I am trying to launch an new activity from my main activity. I have:

```
    Button butt = new Button(this);
    butt.setText("Colors");
    butt.setBackgroundColor(paintCanvas.currentColor());
    butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PaintCanvas.this, PaletteActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
```

This launches the new activity and then immediately throws the error:

```
10-18 01:41:01.090  28582-28582/com.deekor.fingerpainting E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value android.graphics.Path@415c3c68
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1235)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:622)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1195)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1170)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSparseArray(Parcel.java:662)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1198)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1170)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1619)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:2078)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:2874)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Whats going wrong? One my views uses paths, but why would that affect me stating a new activity?

Comment: post full stack trace of crash

Comment: have you overriden `saveInstance` in parcelActivity ?

Comment: @Dante I don't have a `parcelActivity` in one of my views I have overwritten `onSaveInstanceState`

Comment: sorry i meant PaintCanvas activity

Comment: @Dante on of the views in that activity has overwritten `onSaveInstanceState`

Comment: try removing it and then running again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a `Path` is not serializable. I had to create my own class that implements serializable.

Answer (score 0):

The Path class doesn't have anything in it that wouldn't be serializable so you can get away with using the following class instead of Path.

```
public class SerializablePath extends Path implements Serializable {
}
```